# Integration... by parts? (For question on convolution theorem)

Tags: integration

I am doing a question on convolution theorem for the inverse laplace transform, except I can't seem to figure out how to do the integral.. I tried by parts but I can't get an answer without $\tau$ in it.

Question, to find inverse laplace transform of:$$H(s)=\frac{1}{s^2(s+2)}$$

I have gotten up to:

$$\mathcal{L^{-1}}(H(s))=e^{-2t}\int_0^t\tau e^{2\tau}d\tau$$

Apparently the answer is $\frac14(e^{-2t}+2t-1)$ ?

Comment: $\int_0^t \tau e^{2\tau}\,d\tau = \left[\frac{\tau e^{2\tau}}{2}\right]_0^t - \frac{1}{2}\int_0^t e^{2\tau}\,d\tau$.

Comment: Thanks again. I didn't realise you simply just subbed in the bounds for the $\frac{\tau e^{2\tau}}{2}$ bit.

Answer (score 1):

You could find the $\mathcal{L}^{-1}(H)$ by writing $H(s)$ as:

$$H(s)=\frac{1}{2s^2}+\frac{1}{4(s+2)}-\frac{1}{4s}$$ and then use the basic formulas :

$$\mathcal{L}(t^n)=\frac{n!}{s^{n+1}}, \mathcal{L}(e^{at})=\frac{1}{s-a}$$

Note that considering @Daniel' comment: $$\int\tau e^{2\tau}d\tau=\frac{1}{2}\times\frac{1}{2}\times\int(2\tau)e^{2\tau}d(2\tau)=\frac{1}{4}\int u e^udu,(u=2\tau)=...$$

Comment: $\quad +1\quad \ddot\smile$